# How to use gspread with python-social-auth

Tags: python-social-auth, gspread

I'm trying to use gspread with python-social-auth, I followed the sample describe on documentation and I've created this class to use as credential store:

```
class Credentials(object):
    def __init__ (self, access_token=None, scope=None):
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.scope=scope

    def refresh (self, http):
        # get new access_token
        # this only gets called if access_token is None
        pass
```

And at my code I've used:

```
import gspread

credentials = Credentials(access_token=user.social_auth.get_access_token(),
              scope=['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])
sh = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

And asking any response from API using:

```
sh.get_spreadsheets_feed()
```

This error appears on the console:

```
*** RequestError: (401, '401: <HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n')
```

I have defined the scope at my settings and this is working well, for example trying to get contacts from Google Contacts

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly' 
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these scopes also to Python Social Auth settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    ...
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
]
```